# Cannot Set Value to Variable in Mule ESB

Tags: web-services, mule, setvalue

I tried to get value from soap using Web Consumer, then I want to get the value with set-variable.

the problem, i can get the value to input in set-variabel.

this the design.

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwBRG.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but I think you are trying to extract value from SOAP response. If this is the case, then note that Web Service consumer returns NamespaceRestorerXMLStreamReader.

You can drag "Transform Message" which is Mule DataWeave Transform Component from palette and drop it after Web Service Consumer component. You will then notice response structure in the left hand side. Define appropriate output format in right side and map the elements as needed.

You can then extract values to store in flow variable and continue with further logic.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dom to xml the use xpath in a variable to pick the value